# How to detect USB 4.0 on Linux?

Tags: lsusb

I've bought this Lenovo laptop https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/p/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-slim-series-laptops/lenovo-legion-slim-7-gen-8-(16-inch-amd)/len101g0029#tech_specs that is supposed to support USB 4.0. However the `lsusb -t` return this output:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

I can't see any speed rate more than 10000M. In my other laptop with Thunderbolt 4, I can see 20000M.
I use PopOS

```
$ uname -a
Linux pop-os 6.5.4-76060504-generic
```

The Linux kernel 6.5.4 should detect the USB4 isn't it?

Did I miss something? Did Lenovo install wrong hardware ports on my laptop? Should I return this laptop?

Comment: AFAIK, USB4 does not necessarily imply a host/port supports >10Gbps data transfer mode. At least earlier spec seems to mandate only Tunneled USB 3.2 Gen 2×1. (It might still provide higher total bandwidth, which can be used for DP or PCIe tunneling, than the so-to-speak 3.2 Gen 2 port; but say when connecting a USB/UAS drive, you still get 10Gbps at max.)

Comment: I don't know about the Legion line but in *my* experience with the IdeaPad line, Lenovo is quite "cheap" when it comes to their USB port / internal hub / chip. I bought one with Ryzen 4800U, none of its ports are 10Gbps ones, while some other cheap laptops I got from vendor like Chuwi or Alldocube, both of them provides me a 10Gbps type-c port. (The Alldocube one was even some really low-end JasperLake Celeron one.) (Although the IdeaPad does have two type-c ports instead of one.)

Comment: @TomYan you are right. The USB4 spec doesn't mandate the OEM to produce a USB4 host to support 20Gpbs or even 40Gbps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB4. That is a joke and just a marketing bulshit.